# undifined error of $scope variable in angularjs

Tags: asp.net-mvc, angularjs, e-commerce

I am developing an eCommerce website asp.net mvc with angularjs. I am getting some issue with $scope in one of my page.I define an $scope.items array in my controller and trying to fetch values in this array from cookies.
here is the code

```
app.controller('checkoutController', ['$scope', 'productService', '$cookies', '$cookieStore', '$location', 'sharedService', '$rootScope', 'customerService', function ($scope, productService, $cookies, $cookieStore, $location, sharedService, $rootScope, customerService) {
    $scope.items = [];

    $scope.customer = {};
    $scope.customer.FirstName = "";
    $scope.customer.LastName = "";
    $scope.customer.Email = "";
    $scope.customer.Password = "";
    $scope.customer.CPassword = "";
    $scope.customer.Address1 = "";
    $scope.customer.Address2 = "";
    $scope.customer.ZipCode = "";
    $scope.customer.Country = "";
    $scope.customer.State = "";
    $scope.customer.City = "";
    $scope.customer.MobileNo = "";

    $scope.logDetails = {};
    $scope.logDetails.LogEmail = "";
    $scope.logDetails.LogPassword = "";
    $scope.customer.Roleid = 1; 
   $scope.items = $cookies.StyleStoreCart;
}
```

it gives me error that $scope.items is not defined. but its already defined

Experts please tell me where i m going wrong?

here is the url of live website. Please try to checkout and see error in console on checkout page.

http://stylesstore.com/Home/Products

here is the way I am inserting data to cookies in my application in my product page

```
var item = new cartItem(Picture1, ProductName, UnitPrice);
        $scope.items.push(item); 
        $cookies.StyleStoreCart = $scope.items 
        $scope.Itemcount = $scope.Itemcount + 1
```

and in my checkout page I am getting the cookies values like this

```
 $scope.items = $cookies.StyleStoreCart;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because `items` is assigned to `undefined` before you access it.

In your first line of code, you initialize `items` as an array, but  `$cookieStore.get('StyleStoreCart')` is `undefined`, then `$scope.items` became `undefined` after this assignment.

### Update

`Home` page stores `StyleStoreCart` in cookies successfully, but if you take a look at this cookie item using developer tool (in Chrome, it's chrome://settings/cookies), you'll see this cookie's path is `/home`. Then you navigate to `http://stylesstore.com/Cart/CheckOut`, whose path is `/cart`, that's maybe we can't get `StyleStoreCart` from cookies.

A proper solution is, store cookies as below

```
$cookies.put('StyleStoreCart', value, {path: "/"});
```

Comment: but m getting this from cookies and my cookies is not null.. :(

Comment: but from the website, `$cookieStore.get('StyleStoreCart')` turns out to be `undefined`

Comment: i am also trying to find the reason .. from the product page it is assigning data to the cookies but in checkout page its show undefined.. I donot know why. I update my question please see how I am assigning and  getting data from cookies

Comment: thanks I will try it and update u what was the result :)